# Swift Protocol Oriented Networking code crashing Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Playing around in playground with protocol oriented networking code and on the last line where I bring everything together, Xcode crashes by saying

> LLDB RPC server has crashed... and so on

There must be something terrifically wrong in my code and I'm sure it's on the last couple of lines but I can't figure it out.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

struct Repo {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

extension Repo {
    init?(dict: JSONDict) {
        guard let id = dict["id"] as? Int, let name = dict["name"] as? String else { return nil }
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

typealias JSONDict = [String:Any]

protocol Resource {
    associatedtype Content
    var url: URL { get }
    func parse(data: Data) -> Content?
}

extension Resource {
    func parseJSON(data: Data) -> Any? {
        let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
        return json
    }
}

struct RepoService: Resource {
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/users/mkchoi212/repos")!

    func parse(data: Data) -> [Repo]? {
        guard let dictArray = self.parseJSON(data: data) as? [JSONDict] else { return nil }
        return dictArray.flatMap(Repo.init)
    }
}

final class WebService<Content> {
    func load<R: Resource>(resource: R, completion: @escaping (R.Content?) -> ()) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: resource.url) { data, _, _ in
            let res = data.flatMap(resource.parse)
            completion(res)
        }.resume()
    }
}

WebService().load(resource: RepoService) { res in
    for elem in res {
        print(elem)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: My first suggestion would be to make it a compiled project. Then you can set breakpoints and debug your code ...

Comment: @MartinR I did and it just seg faults before it even succeeds building

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A crashing compiler is a bug and should be reported. Xcode 9 (beta) does not
crash with your code but gives helpful error messages leading to a solution:

```
error: generic parameter 'Content' could not be inferred
WebService().load(resource: RepoService) { res in
             ^
```

The generic placeholder `Content` in `class WebService<Content>` is
not used at all, remove it and make the class non-generic. Then:

```
error: generic parameter 'R' could not be inferred
WebService().load(resource: RepoService) { res in
             ^
```

You have to pass an *instance* of `RepoService` to the `load` method,
and `res` inside the closure is an optional.

With these changes

```
final class WebService {
    func load<R: Resource>(resource: R, completion: @escaping (R.Content?) -> ()) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: resource.url) { data, _, _ in
            let res = data.flatMap(resource.parse)
            completion(res)
            }.resume()
    }
}

WebService().load(resource: RepoService()) { res in
    guard let res = res else { return }
    for elem in res {
        print(elem)
    }
}
```

your code compiles and runs as expected, in Xcode 8.3.3 and 9.

Comment: Appreciate it. I will make sure to go ahead and report it as a bug for Xcode 8.3.3

Answer (score 0):

working example

```
import Foundation

import PlaygroundSupport

struct Repo {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}

extension Repo {
    init?(dict: JSONDict) {
        guard let id = dict["id"] as? Int, let name = dict["name"] as? String else { return nil }
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}

typealias JSONDict = [String:Any]

protocol Resource {
    associatedtype Content
    var url: URL { get }
    func parse(data: Data) -> Content?
}

extension Resource {
    func parseJSON(data: Data) -> Any? {
        let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)
        return json
    }
}

struct RepoService: Resource {
    let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/users/mkchoi212/repos")!

    func parse(data: Data) -> [Repo]? {
        guard let dictArray = self.parseJSON(data: data) as? [JSONDict] else { return nil }
        return dictArray.flatMap(Repo.init)
    }
}

final class WebService {
    func load<R: Resource>(resource: R, completion: @escaping (R.Content) -> ()) {
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: resource.url) { data, _, _ in
            if let res = data.flatMap(resource.parse) {
                completion(res)
            }
            }.resume()
    }
}

WebService().load(resource: RepoService()) { res in
    for elem in res {
        print(elem)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

gave me this result

```
Repo(id: 93473150, name: "bitbuf")
Repo(id: 28517340, name: "DIJKASTRAS")
Repo(id: 71310619, name: "git-strbuf")
Repo(id: 30558002, name: "Habitats-master")
Repo(id: 28517464, name: "Home-Automation-Project")
Repo(id: 33394787, name: "hw.")
Repo(id: 39911528, name: "JPSThumbnailAnnotation")
Repo(id: 37162894, name: "M3")
Repo(id: 39709018, name: "Maroon")
Repo(id: 41267183, name: "mkchoi212.github.io")
Repo(id: 28519262, name: "Money-Saving-Meals")
Repo(id: 39857111, name: "MRCircularProgressView")
Repo(id: 81773538, name: "papers-we-love")
Repo(id: 37074317, name: "socket.io-client-swift")
Repo(id: 28519322, name: "Wordsneak")
```